# CSS/HTML <div> behind the image and cover max height

Tags: html, css

I want to make a box at the bottom of the image colliding together without any space where i could write text.

[The problems](http://www.part.lt/img/2c971ae229192b9ee2fd8a7df423e7da350.png)

Padding is 0. I want something that will not move any images and destroy the layout.

HTML:

```
<div id="pl">
    <img src="Images/mcdonalds.jpg" width="300px" height="180px />
</div>
<div id="pm">
    <img src="Images/cilipica.jpg" width="300px" height="180px" />
</div>
<div id="pr">
    <img src="Images/mythay.jpg" width="300px" height="180px" />
</div>
<div id="plbox">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#plbox {
    width: 300px;
    height: 180px;
    background: #47c9af;
    position: relative;
}
```

By the way, my website's cover is not colliding with the top of the browser either, any tips? Thanks for answers, i really appreciate them.

Comment: Are your margins set to 0?

Comment: Kind of tough to see what's going on when all we have is an image to go off of. Is there a URL we can go to to inspect the page?

Comment: Have you reset the browser using css reset ?

Comment: 1) Margins are 0 yes
2) No i am running the page on localhost
3) Never heard about css reset

Comment: visit for the most basic version of CSS reset: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/no_css_reset and http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: CodeRomeos thank you very much! My cover is now touching the top of the browser as i wanted but there is still a little gap between the image and the green box. I would like to see that box more like under the image a little bit if that is possible.

Comment: try this `#plbox{ margin-top: -2px ... }`  (or another `-number`)

Comment: Don't use negative margins to fix this, it's not necessary.

Comment: Are your images just not hitting the full height?

Answer (score 0):

add the property:

```
overflow: auto;
```

in the parent div or in a container if you use .

Answer (score 0):

One common solution to this is to apply `display:block` to affected images.

Whether this changes the layout of your page or not depends on how the bottom images are positioned, but try to `display:block` to these images specifically and see if it helps.

```
#pl img,
#pm img,
#pr img{
  display:block;
  // you may also need the line below
  // float:left;
}
```